# How run `aws s3 sync` during docker compose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, aws-cli

Here is snippet for aws s3 sync command:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  amazon-aws-cli-download-test-data:  
    image: amazon/aws-cli:2.13.0 # <- newest version for today
    command:
#       | `aws` main command was also tried and error was the same
#      \/ 
#     - aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/myfolder/ /s3/mybucket/myfolder/ --delete
      - s3 sync s3://mybucket/myfolder/ /s3/mybucket/myfolder/ --delete
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - AWS_REGION
    volumes:
      - './test-data/s3:/s3'
```

The error:

```
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

The `s3` command is the oldest that definitely present in all aws cli's. What is wrong? How execute some s3 syncing during containmer start up?

Comment: The `-` denotes a list element in YAML. Try just using `command: s3 sync s3://mybucket/myfolder/ /s3/mybucket/myfolder/ --delete` all on a single line. Passing the command as a list element is messing it up I think.

Comment: It'd be the same effect as putting the entire command line into a single single-quoted word at a shell prompt.  Each list item is a separate shell word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to

```
command: s3 sync s3://mybucket/myfolder/ /s3/mybucket/myfolder/ --delete
```

fixed the issue